# Construct a unitary operator U on H with prescribed spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Given an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$. Let $|\lambda_k| = 1$ for $k = 1, ..., n$. Construct a unitary operator $U$ on $H$ such that $\sigma(U) = \{\lambda_k\}$ for $k=1,....,n.$

I can approach this question with orthonormal basis and Fourier's series.

Comment: Just use a multiplication operator?

Comment: Let $e_n$ be a basis and let $Ux = \sum_n \lambda_n \langle e_n, x \rangle e_n$.

Comment: @minimalrho Your comment could be an answer.